# variable sharing? Batch CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sharing

I'm trying to set 2 variables in 3 categories, 6 variables total, copying out the categories three times seems like a poor option especially because my real code is much larger than this with almost 10 categories with 30 variables each.

First I ask which category to set variable (constant) and then asked to set the two variables in that category.

Which is fine, until I want to do something with the combined variable.

```
@echo off
cls

:start

cls
echo which variable do you want to set?
echo (1),(2),(3)
choice /c 123 /n
if ERRORLEVEL 3 goto :3
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto :2
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :1

:1
set const=one
goto :wizard

:2
set const=two
goto :wizard

:3
set const=three
goto :wizard

:wizard
set /p %const%_varA= set %const% variableA: 
set /p %const%_varB= set %const% variableB: 

:: this line is the problem
echo %%const%_varA%
echo %%const%_varB%
:: 
echo.
pause
goto :filewrite

echo.

:filewrite
echo one varA %one_varA%
echo one varB %one_varB%
echo two varA %two_varA%
echo two varB %two_varB%
echo three varA %three_varA%
echo three varB %three_varB%

pause
goto :start
```

Comment: What value is supposed to be in that variable? You are setting the values of `%const%_var1/2` but never of anything with `_varA` at then end.

Comment: sorry going to A/B was a last minute change to make it easier to understand and i missed changing out a few lines :S.

Comment: All good, spotted and fixed again

Comment: No problem, @geisterfurz007, ryan already fixed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played around a bit and the problem you have is the fact that in batch-files the way to escape a `%` is another one. So your code will eventually look like `echo %const%_varA%` and as `%var_A%` is empty/does not exist, the only thing you should be getting is `%const` as output.

Luckily there is a way to bring another character into the game to prevent this from happening. Adding `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` under the first line will make variables accessable using exclamation marks. This is usually used to access variables in closed sets of parenthesis but comes in handy for this one:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set const=three
set %const%_varA=foo
echo Without exclamationmarks: %%const%_varA%
echo With exclamationmarks   : !%const%_varA!
pause
```

Is a tiny example that demonstrates the problem.
The upper line is what you currently have and not working. The lower one however uses above explaned delayed expansion.
Meaning: First (`%`) the value of `%const%` is calculated, changing the line to `echo [...] !three_varA!` and *after* (`!`) comes the whole thing!

Feel free to ask questions :)

Comment: oops.. i meant to write... i did play around with    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion  and !  from what i read elsewhere but must have had the wrong combination. your explanation makes send now. appreciate the help. thanks!